# Select by date search result of a site with Python

Tags: python, search, web

I have a source page of a search result like this (only a slice of it, of course):

```
<div class="search-results-list-item clearfix is-collapsed is-topad-list-item ">


<div class="list-item-data">
    <h2 class="list-item-title">
        <a href="http://www.mylink.com" name="61492088">Description</a>
    </h2>

            <div class="list-item-location">
        <span>Rimini</span>
    </div>
        </div>

<div class="list-item-price">
    <span>2.000 &euro;</span>
</div>

<div class="list-item-actdate">
    <span>16 February</span>
</div>

</div>
```

My program should print only links (in the example, the link contained in "list-item-data" div class) which have in the "list-item-actdate" the word "Today". Other links should not be printed, so in my example the only link in the code will not be printed.

I thought of using BeautifulSoup but I don't know how to use it for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using `lxml.html` instead of BeautifulSoup... It uses XPath to search the document and extract the relevant parts. It should hopefully give you an idea how to process HTML (or XML) documents...

```
import lxml.html

# Parse the HTML document
html = lxml.html.parse(open('/path/to/source/file').read())

# find div elements which contains a div child with class='list-item-data'
for parent in html.xpath("//div[@class='list-item-data']/.."):

    # get and check the date
    # note xpath returns a list of elements, here we assume only the first match is of 
    # interest (based on the stated structure of the document)
    date = parent.xpath("./div[@class='list-item-actdate']/span")[0].text
    if not date.startswith("Today "):
        continue

    # print the link address
    href = parent.xpath(".//a")[0].attrib['href']
    print href
```